# import matplotlib failing with No module named _tkinter on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to use `matplotlib` in my application. I created a virtualenv in python2.7, pip installed matplotlib, and it's successfully running on local.

However, when I deploy the app to `heroku` (after `pip freeze` and other steps necessary), my app crashes. When I check the log, I see the following:

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

It's weird because the app was successfully running on local under venv. Is the heroku python environment not configured to run `matplotlib`? If so, what steps should I take to enable that?

Comment: Suppose you were to use `matplotlib.show` in the code. Where would you expect the figure to show up? On a monitor at the server farm? (Why would there be one in the first place?) In the user's web browser? (How should it translate from a GUI window into HTML?) Something else?

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This will set your Matplotlib [backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) to use Agg instead of Tk. Just worked for me at least :-)

Comment: for sake of correctness, `import matplotlib` before anything else.

Comment: Also, you need to make sure to put this line before any other packages that might also be importing matplotlib, e.g., skimage